# spawn a child process using ruby

Tags: ruby

Am new to ruby.
I have a terminal command to exeute some process and output the result as an xml file.(it is working properly fine via terminal)

```
cmd = '"C:\Program Files\shark\hark"  -f "ains 02:04" -eT xml > test12.xml'
```

i need to execute this command using ruby code.

But when i tried using ruby code it outputs the xml file and its contents will be zero.if i quit the terminal using `CTRL + C` i will get the full data inside the xml file

For exiting the child process i tried to kill the process and killed the ruby.exe from the task list .But nothing happned in the xml file.its contents is still zero

code

```
def execute 
   cmd = '"C:\Program Files\shark\hark"  -f "ains 02:04" -eT xml > test12.xml'
  @pid = Process.spawn(cmd)
  sleep(100)
  exec( 'Taskkill /F /IM ruby.exe' )
end
execute
```

whats wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Process.wait` doesn't support stream redirection. In other words, `|`, `>`, `>>` and `<` don't work.